# Facebook sharer link with text parameters

Tags: javascript, facebook

I want to include a link to a URL in a Facebook sharer link, like this one on the *Boston Globe*: http://www.bostonglobe.com/sports/2015/02/06/for-bruins-brad-marchand-agitation-occupation/zoswHyd3pX2yc1pKk5gOdO/story.html

This is the code that I have, but it doesn't show the title:

```
<a aria-label="Share on Facebook" title="Share on Facebook" href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=1http%3A%2F%2Fwww.affinnova.com%2Fconsumer-iq-test%2Fhome.html&t=Do+you+know+what+consumers+want?+Test+your+ability+to+predict+what+new+product+ideas+consumers+want?"
       onclick="javascript:window.open(this.href, '', 'menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,height=300,width=600');return false;"target="_blank" title="Share on Facebook">
    <img src="img/icon-facebook.png" alt="Facebook" />
</a>
```

The pop-up shows the title of the HTML page from the link and the url. I'd like this to be more like what the *Boston Globe* link shows. How can I do that? Do I need an additional script?

Answer (score 7):

```
https://www.facebook.com/share.php?u=google.com&quote=your+text+goes+here
```

I have been using this fro several years. Works fine thus far.

Comment: This is not working for me @Rossitten. Can you share the whole HTML you use with this?

Comment: @Franco - this is the whole code (which, of course, should be wrapped in <a></a> on the site). copy, paste to the address bar and hit ENTER (make sure you are logged in on FB). I have been using this for a good while now - it works.

Answer (score 0):

My friend, sharer.php is deprecated.
http://www.joshuawinn.com/facebooks-sharer-php-longer-deprecated-2014/

Use dialogs instead.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog/v2.2?locale=es_LA

Good luck!

Comment: I've seen that documentation, but there are no good examples and the code isn't clear. Do I have to add any a Facebook JavaScript Library on my page?

Comment: Sure, Facebook's JavaScript SDK, as seen in that link.